# SQL Server 2012 event ID 18487

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Good morning guys.  We have a SQL 2012 instance we use to store data on the parts we create.  We have software that goes and pulls data out of the PLC on the machine and dumps the data into the SQL Database.  We have not run the machine since 12/21/15.  Over the weekend I did a windows update on the server (Which is virtual) and rebooted it.  Since then the software that dumps the data cannot reach the database.  I checked the event log and found a constant flow of Error ID 18487 outlining the the password has expired.  The login that the software is using is set with Windows Authentication and the password is set to never expire.  I double checked everything and even changed the password and still getting the constant 18487.  I had double checked all of my settings and I dont understand what may be going on.  Are you guys familiar with this or could a windows update have caused this issue?

Comment: Are the events referencing a domain account or a local account?

Comment: Login failed for user 'admin'.  Reason: The password of the account has expired. [CLIENT: 192.168.0.18]

Comment: That implies that is not using Windows authentication to connect to the db. Do `select * from sys.server_principals where name='admin'` to confirm that there's an account by that name. You can also check the SQL Server logs for failed authentication attempts.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot check the SQL log because this account does not have privilege and my sa account is disabled.  When I ran the query you wrote it came back with 0 results.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue resolved.  Somehow the software changed the login ID that it uses to access the SQL database.  Since it was using Windows Authentication it somehow erased the domain and just left the user login.  Once I changed this everything started working.